# Finding the averages of a text file using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, average

I have a text file with 922 rows and 11 columns. I need to separate them by columns, and then find the average of all 922 numbers in each column. I am a beginner so bear with me. I'm struggling the most with getting the numbers into the array correctly, and the first row are words so i don't know what to do with them. Here's what i have so far. Any help with what to put to store the data as type int would be helpful. thank you.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("eeg.txt")))
                    { 
                    int[] sCurrentLine;
                    while ((br.readLine()) != null) {


                        int[] information = ;
                        int time = information[0];
                        int attention = information[1];
                        int med = information[2];
                        int delta = information[3];
                        int theta = information[4];
                        int lA = information[5];
                        int hA = information[6];
                        int lB = information[7];
                        int hB = information[8];
                        int lG = information[9];
                        int hG = information[10];

}

}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the line you read into a string, then parse the string into an array of ints:

```
String someLine = "";
while ((someLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String strArray [] = someLine.split();
    int[] information = new int[strArray.length];
    for (int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
        information[i] = Integer.parse(strArray[i]);
    }
    // process the information array
}
```